# Laravel store scheduled tasks in mysql

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to be able to let my users schedule tasks but have the task stored in a MySQL database.

This is so that tasks can be shown in a table and canceled whenever the user wants.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is a little bit broad, I'll say how I would do it.
If it doesn't fit, tell me and we can think about a different solution.

### First step: Managing Tasks

Take a look at [Laravel Queue](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Queue/Failed/DatabaseFailedJobProvider.html#method_log). That would be a good starting point.
See how their closures from jobs are stored into database when they fail. Then abstract the logic into a model and you will be able to perform CRUD and other operations at it.

### Second step: Running Tasks

Now you can attach model events upon `saving` and with it, using [Scheduler](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands), you can run the task using the given time. Attach a `deleting` event too, to stop the task.

Comment: I don't want it to present a list of failed jobs to the user, I want them to see jobs that are scheduled to run. I want all scheduled jobs to be stored in the database, containing all the relevant data such as when to run and how often.

Comment: @imperium2335 I know, I'm sorry that my text isn't clear enough. What I'm saying is that failed jobs are indeed saved to database (if you config it), a process that would be ***similar*** to what you want, so you could take a look at its logic and figure one out for your problem.